# How to translate/map hashes

Tags: ruby

I've been given the task to create a "secret code" translator. It is supposed to take input from the user and then map/translate it using a "converter" hash. The code I currently have looks like this.

```
array = []

converter = {
  "A" => "Z",
  "B" => "Y",
  "C" => "X",
  "D" => "W",
  "E" => "V",
  "F" => "U",
  "G" => "T",
  "H" => "S",
  "I" => "R",
  "J" => "Q",
  "K" => "P",
  "L" => "O",
  "M" => "N",
  "N" => "M",
  "O" => "L",
  "P" => "K",
  "Q" => "J",
  "R" => "I",
  "S" => "H",
  "T" => "G",
  "U" => "F",
  "V" => "E",
  "W" => "D",
  "X" => "C",
  "Y" => "B",
  "Z" => "A"
}

puts "Enter a phrase to translate"
start = gets.chomp

array = start.split("")

start_hash = {"input" => array}

print start_hash["input"]

index = 0

while index < start_hash["input"].length
  print start_hash["input"]
  index += 1
end
```

I'm not 100% sure I'm on the right path. So if I input code, the output would be something like this:

```
code = xlwv
```

I'm super lost and any help you guys might be able to offer would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: [`tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-tr) and [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) which takes a look-up table as an argument.

Comment: You're not actually doing any translation in this code. Try changing `start_hash["input"][i]` each iteration of the `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simpler ways to do what you are looking for. Since you've taken a shot at it before asking for help, I'll break it down for you.

In particular, `map` is the easiest way to run through an array and transform its values to something else. Before I explain how to do that, you have a couple of other problems to address.

First, if you're looking up capital letters in a hash, you need your input to be capital letters. So:

```
puts "Enter a phrase to translate:"
phrase = gets.chomp.upcase
```

Now, `chars` is simpler than using `split('')` and does the same thing:

```
arr = phrase.chars
```

Next, you can use `map` to alter your array:

```
new_arr = arr.map do |c|
  converter[c]
end
```

This will go through your array one by one, setting `c` equal to each array element value (in other words, each character) in turn. Then, the result of whatever is inside your `do` loop gets plugged into an array. When `map` gets to the last element in the array being mapped, it returns the new array that it has been plugging values into.

So, `c` becomes your hash key, and `converter[c]` is the hash value for that key. That hash value is the value that gets plugged into your new array. The result of the call to `map` will be your encrypted string in array form.

Finally, join the result of the `map` call into a string:

```
new_phrase = new_arr.join
```

Now, you don't need all those lines of code and extra variables to get that result — I did that to help you look at the problem one step at a time. Once you have used `gets` to get your `phrase` variable, you can easily pull the rest of the code into a single line:

```
new_phrase = phrase.chars.map { |c| converter[c] }.join
```

And there you have it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help, Bob - I appreciate it!

Comment: @ddybas If this works for you, perhaps you can accept it as the answer.